# VBScript command to wait for files to be extracted before launching EXE to install program

Tags: vbscript, zip, extract

I'm looking at having a script that decompresses a file (PDMsetup.zip) and then launch the executable that it extracts.

```
ZipFile="PDMsetup.zip"
ExtractTo=".\"
 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sourceFile = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(ZipFile)
destFolder = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(ExtractTo)
 
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(sourceFile).Items()
objShell.NameSpace(destFolder).copyHere FilesInZip, 16
 
Set fso = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
Set FilesInZip = Nothing

wscript.sleep 480000

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile) 
strPath = strFolder &  "\Startwinstall.exe"
objShell.Run strPath
```

I want to get rid of;

```
wscript.sleep 480000
```

and replace it with a command that tells the script wait until the extraction is done before launching startwinstall.exe

I've kept adjusting the wait time to make up for differences in PC performance with the extraction, but a command to just 'wait' until it's done would be preferential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete any previous copy of the installer exe in the target folder and then wait for that file to be created. Create your objects once at the top of the script. And there's no need to set the objects to Nothing. That will happen automatically when the script ends. The edited script is below:

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oWSH = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

MyFolder = oFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) 
ExtractTo = ".\"
ZipFile = "PDMsetup.zip"
StartApp = ExtractTo & "Startwinstall.exe"
On Error Resume Next
oFSO.DeleteFile StartApp
On Error Goto 0

sourceFile = oFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(ZipFile)
destFolder = oFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(ExtractTo)

Set FilesInZip = oApp.NameSpace(sourceFile).Items()
oApp.NameSpace(destFolder).copyHere FilesInZip, 16

Do Until oFSO.FileExists(StartApp)
  WScript.Sleep 1000
Loop

oWSH.Run StartApp
```

**Note:** I assigned a `MyFolder` variable, but it's not currently being used. `ExtractTo = ".\"` could be changed to `ExtractTo = MyFolder`. You could also eliminate the `GetAbsolutePathName` lines if you are using `MyFolder` with the ZipFile name. There are always many ways to do the same thing.

**Note:** I think the above can be done with a much briefer (probably two line) PowerShell script. Let me know if you're interested in that solution.

Comment: Hi @LesFerch

Thanks for the script! It successfully decompressed, but it's prompting with UAC which won't work for this remote SW push. 

Need to launch startswinstall.exe without a UAC prompt. I Got it to 'work' by using a system service account previously but ran into other issues that prevented a complete solution. 

We use Desktop central (new to me) and I'm trying to pre-stage an install by copying a zip file to c:\temp\PDMinstaller on remote machines and decompressing it. 

Then running a configuration on D-DAY VIA desktop central that installs the SW silently, if possible.

Comment: Whenever I try to leverage a PS script, it opens in frickin' notepad because windows by default wont run remote PS scripts. If I take the same script and double click it locally, it works perfectly. Prefer not to toy with registry if possible, but don't have a great solution yet.

Comment: You're going to have to use the SYSTEM account and repackage the installer if necessary (ask the software vendor to supply a non-interactive installer). It may require two parts. A silent, SYSTEM installable package for the machine components and user package for the user profile. It's been done like that in big companies for decades and typically pushed out using SMS/SCCM/ECM (which coordinates the machine/user pieces, logs the errors, yada, yada).

Comment: The UAC prompt you're seeing is not a function of the script. The script is just extracting an Exe and running it. The Exe must be requesting elevated privileges.

Comment: Hi @LesFerch, thanks for the info! I got the PS script working remotely, I had to use an inline command to tell the PC to actually use powershell. 

Now, I'm trying to figure out a way to run the installer without being prmpted by the UAC. system account doesn't work, admin accounts dont work. I can push a remote registry entry that changes the consentprmptbehaviouradmin key, but I'd like to do it (if possible) without modifying reg keys.....

For reference, I'm using ManageEngine Desktop Central for asset and softwre management.

Comment: Have you considered using the built-in Administrator account to run the installer? UAC is OFF for Administrator, so using that account won't require disabling UAC for any other account. Administrator is disabled by default, so the first challenge would be enabling that account (if you haven't already done so).

Comment: If my answer does answer your original question, please click the checkmark. Thanks.